# How do I change timing for NSTimer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have the following code:

```
timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.50 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain];    

-(void) onTimer 
{
}
```

After every 0.50 seconds the `OnTimer` method is called.

But now I want to increment the time-interval.

That means:

```
OnTimer calls after 0.55
OnTimer calls after 0.60
OnTimer calls after 0.65
OnTimer calls after 0.70
OnTimer calls after 0.75
& so on.
```

Is there any solution for this?? I have tried lot but its not working.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sure you can do this. Change `repeats:YES` to `repeats:NO` so that the timer doesn't repeat, and then in `onTimer`, just start a new timer with a longer interval. You need a variable to hold your interval so that you can make it a bit longer each time through `onTimer`. Also, you probably don't need to retain the timer anymore, as it will only fire once, and when it does, you'll get a new timer.

I'm no Objective-C expert (or iOS expert...) and it's been a while but I think something like this:

```
float gap = 0.50;

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:gap target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void) onTimer {
    gap = gap + .05;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:gap target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Something like that? Oh, and I'm really not too sure about the `retain` semantics here... read the docs to make sure you don't leak!

Comment: The NSTimer object will be automatically dealloced when the timer ends.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one solution to Hardik's question using NSTimer's fireDate property (written in Swift):

**Swift 2**

```
var timeInterval = 0.50
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval, target: self, selector: Selector("onTimer:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func onTimer(timer: NSTimer) {
    timeInterval += 0.05
    timer.fireDate = timer.fireDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(timeInterval)
}
```

**Swift 3, 4, 5**

```
var timeInterval = 0.50
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(self.onTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func onTimer(timer: Timer) {
    timeInterval += 0.05
    timer.fireDate = timer.fireDate.addingTimeInterval(timeInterval)
}
```

Comment: you cannot _re-fire_ a timer like this.

Comment: for me it works. Here is the code: 
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/86005ed7049e985a34f6

And btw. the timer has repeat on true and I am just setting the next fire date.

Comment: As far as I read the documentation for NSTimer using setFireDate is absolutely fine (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/setFireDate:).

Comment: Had a go at it, @user1415206 's code works like a charm.
One thing though: I'd use `selector: Selector("onTimer:")` instead of the plain string `selector: "onTimer:"`

Answer (score 4):

You could try adjusting the timer's FireDate, see  `setFireDate`

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the interval at which a timer fires. No way. There's no API for doing this.

Two obvious workarounds: If you *always* change the interval, then you can just change the next time that the timer fires; this has precedence over the timer interval. Of course you have to do that every time the timer fires. If you *sometimes* change the interval, just invalidate the first timer and create a new timer with the new interval.

Answer (score 0):

This just work like charm for me.

```
- (void)FlexibleTimer {
    if (!keyTimer) {
        keyTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.intervalOfIdleTimer
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(keyTimerExceeded)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
    }
    else {
        if (fabs([keyTimer.fireDate timeIntervalSinceNow]) < self.intervalOfIdleTimer - 1.0) {
            [keyTimer setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:self.intervalOfIdleTimer]];
        }
    }
}

- (void)keyTimerExceeded {
    [self setNextDelayForFlexibleTimer];
    [self FlexibleTimer];
    NSLog(@"Timer Exceeded %f", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]);
}
```