# Setting Timerinterval fast then gradually it is slow down

Tags: iphone, ios4, nstimer, nstimeinterval

i have the following code:

```
xx=0.50;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:xx target:self selector:@selector(ontimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)ontimer
{
    xx=xx+0.05;
    NSTimeInterval dt = [timer timeInterval];
    // do something
}
```

I want to call ontimer for 0.50 then 0.55 then 0.60 & soon. that means First Fast then gradually slow down.

The Problem is each Time ontimer will be called for 0.50 seconds.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change timing for NSTimer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152097/how-do-i-change-timing-for-nstimer) Why don’t you edit the original question to make it more clear?

Comment: okey, Now onwards i will take care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting your time variable to static?

Comment: after using static NSTimeInterval my problem has been solved now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

afaik you can't adjust the timeInterval when a timer has been started, so you have to change the fireDate each time. Like this:

```
- (void)someTimerMethod:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
    static NSTimeInterval pause = 0.5;
    pause += 0.05;
    [aTimer setFireDate:[[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:pause] autorelease]];
}

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(someTimerMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks it's working Fine for me. problem is that i am not using Static  NSTimeInterval.